# php temp directory in windows server

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis

hi i am working on windows server iis 7.5 . and i placed my php codeigniter project on the server. the project works fine in the local server. but in the windows server there is error on file uploading. the file uploading class giving error `"The temporary folder is missing."` i checked `phpinfo()` and i got the path of temp directory like this `D:\temp\php\` and when i run the function in php file to see the temp directory path which is `sys_get_temp_dir();` then i get the temp directory path like this `D:\Temp\` i have a folder in server in `D:` drive and also i have the directory with Temp name and that is writeable also but still i am getting the erorr of missing the folder. apart from this i checked the php path using `php_ini_loaded_file()` then i get the path like this `C:\Services\PHP\php.ini.` is this is the problem of different drives and how can i fix this problem ? when i check `is_writable(sys_get_temp_dir())` it returns false.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check your D: and see if you have a Directory by name `temp` and inside that a directory by name `php` and see if the `php` folder is writable.